# Regex whitespace before character

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm looking for a check job to do before pushing commits. I have some json files that might not be properly formatted.

```
{
  "key": "good value.",
  "key2": "bad value. ",
   ...
}
```

I want to find which files contains a JSON key or value that contains a whitespace before the end of the double quote.

I tried :

```
find config/*.json -exec grep '\s(?=[^"\s]*")' {} \;
```

It does not get me any match but it works on https://www.regextester.com/ with the previous example.
Any clue ?

Comment: GNU `grep` needs to be run with `-P` flag if you pass PCRE pattern to it. I do not see how that pattern worked for you online. Try `grep ':[[:space:]]*"[^"]*[[:space:]]"'`

Comment: Thanks ! Manged to make it work with this : \s(?=[^"\s]*") maybe it only work for js ?

Comment: No, it works with any engine supporting lookarounds.